# Payroll department requires my foreign address to determine tax treaty benefits

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am a foreign national staying in the US with an L-2 visa.

My new workplace requires me to state my "foreign address" in order to determine eligibility for "tax treaty benefits".
I am not eligible for such benefits and am no longer a resident of my country of citizenship, but they still require the address.

How exactly can a foreign address be used to determine tax treaty benefits eligibility? I have already stated my nationality.

Comment: Be careful: L-2 visas are non-immigrant visas.  That means you **must** leave the USA at some point.  Where would you go?

Comment: As I was unfamiliar with L-2 status, I discovered it's tied to a spouse or parent's L-1 visa, which after 5-7 years can only be renewed after the L-1 holder goes back to the foreign home office for a year. So: you are not a permanent resident of the United States. You have a residence which is a "permanent place of abode" in the U.S. while you maintain it, but you are not "domiciled" in the U.S.  You are still domiciled in your home country.  Whether that domicile is your last address or otherwise is a legal question about your home jurisdiction.

Comment: One candidate address may be the home office of the L-1 visa holder's employer.  The HR department of this employer may have specific assistance to questions like this for family members like you.

Answer (score 1):

Your nationality doesn't matter for most tax purposes. Where you are living, and where your income originated from, does. The company may want to pay you from a specific office to minimize taxes. They may also need your address in order to file taxes at all. This is a legitimate request.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am no longer a resident of any other country than the US. The IRS considers me a Resident Alien.

Comment: In that case, send them a note saying "No current foreign address" and see what they tell you.

Comment: This is what I did (twice actually), and their response was something along "we must have your foreign address to check for tax treaty benefits". So going back to my question, how exactly can a foreign address be used to determine tax treaty benefits eligibility? Especially when they already know my nationality.

Comment: How it can be used will depend on the country; I don't think we can give a general answer here.